# Why terminal shows "/home/igoru /etc/bash_completion" every time I open it?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell

I've added some lines to `~/.bash_aliases` yesterday... And today my gnome-terminal started showing me this expression in the beginning, just before the prompt.

```
/home/igoru /etc/bash_completion
igoru@igoru-ubuntu:
```

Those are the lines I added:

```
alias realias='vim ~/.bash_aliases; source ~/.bash_aliases'
alias ..='cd ..'
alias .='echo $PWD'
alias canhaz='sudo apt-get install'
```

What is happening?
Is this expression really related to those aliases, or what?

Comment: It is easy to comment these out and recheck fast `:-)`

Comment: That will help you answer your last question and recollect anything else you may have done.

Comment: what? is it meaningful for this question? :S

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"." is a synonym for "source."  Some line in some file is trying to source /etc/bash_completion after you have aliased it to "echo $PWD."

I think realiasing the bash builtins is a bad idea.  Too many scripts will depend on it to act the original way.  Consider "." a reserved keyword.